# SSRS 2008 R2 - How to select dates to remove from a range?

Tags: date, ssrs-2008, range

I am not very familiar with SSRS 2008 R2. I have a report with two parameters : @From, which is the first day of the date range of my report, and  @To which is the last day.

Is there a way to do it easily as PowerPivot does by unselecting values from a dates list ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset or sql :

where
datafield <= @From
and datafield >= @To